# Javascript/jquery autonomous scrolling carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how I can make the following autonmously scroll using javascript? the carousol is going to be placed on google sites using the HTML box so I can't just download a jquery plugin which would be the easiest solution! Jquery is included in the script. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! here is the code:

```
<style>
  .carousel {
  width: 1080px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
 }
 .items {
  width: 1080px;
  position: absolute;
 }
 .items > div {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .items > div > img {
  width: 340px;
  height: 202px;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 .nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 15px;
 }
 .button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
 }
</style>
<div class="carousel" style="display:none;">
 <div class="items">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2wq5nkk.png" border="0" alt="Speaker at event">
  </div>

  <div>
   <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/vfii61.png" border="0" alt="Speaker at event">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/5ttg0z.png" border="0" alt="Speaker at event">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/okpq9g.png" border="0" alt="Speaker at event">
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2h4ywbo.png" border="0" alt="Speaker at event">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/21oyg4x.png" border="0" alt="Speaker at event">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="nav">
  <span class="button left-button">prev</span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="button right-button">next</span>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
 var current_slide = 0; // zero-based
 var slide_count = 2;
 var slide_size = 1080;

 var Direction = {
  LEFT: -1,
  RIGHT: 1
 };

 /**
 * Moves to the next slide using the direction (dx) parameter.
 */
 var nextSlide = function(dx) {
  current_slide = (current_slide + slide_count + dx) % slide_count;

  // Calculate the new value for css 'left' property and animate.
  var left_offset = '-' + (current_slide * slide_size) + 'px';
  $('.items').animate({'left': left_offset}, 1080);
 };

 $('.right-button').click(nextSlide.bind(null, Direction.RIGHT));
 $('.left-button').click(nextSlide.bind(null, Direction.LEFT));


 $('.carousel').show();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easyest way it to add an interval, calling the nextSlide over and over.

```
var nextSlide = function(dx) {
  current_slide = (current_slide + slide_count + dx) % slide_count;

  // Calculate the new value for css 'left' property and animate.
  var left_offset = '-' + (current_slide * slide_size) + 'px';
  $('.items').animate({'left': left_offset}, 1080);
 };

 $('.carousel').show();

setInterval(function(){
    nextSlide(Direction.LEFT);
}, 5000); // Will call nextSlide every 5 seconds
```